# SQL Server: Retrieve the duplicate value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How could I filter out the duplicate value in a column with SQL syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A common question, though filtering out suggests you want to ignore the duplicate ones? If so, listing unique values:

```
SELECT col 
FROM table
GROUP BY col 
HAVING (COUNT(col) =1 )
```

If you just want to filter so you **are left with** the duplicates

```
SELECT col, COUNT(col) AS dup_count
FROM table
GROUP BY col
HAVING (COUNT(col) > 1)
```

Used www.mximize.com/how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-table- as a base in 2009; website content has now gone (2014).

Answer (score 3):

Use **DISTINCT** or GROUP BY** clause.

```
Select DISTINCT City from TableName

OR

Select City from TableName GROUP BY City
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you mean "filter" you could either use [DISTINCT](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/24282/sql_server_24282.html) or maybe [GROUP](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-in-sql-server) BY both are used to Remove or Group duplicate entries.

Check the links for more information.

A snippet from the DISTINCT-link above:

```
SELECT DISTINCT od.productid
FROM [order details] OD

SELECT od.productid
FROM [order details] OD
GROUP BY od.productid
```

Both of these generally result in the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You **asked** for a list of the duplicates.  Here is a simple way using the except operator (SQL 2008 +).

```
  select [column] from Table1 

    except

  select distinct [column] from Table1;
```

Alternatively, you could use standard SQL

```
select [column] from Table1 

where [column} not in 

     (select distinct [column} from Table1);
```

Answer (score 0):

*distinct* would be the keyword to filter douplicates. 
May be you can explain a little more what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question. My "real intent" is to select the rows where the criteria depends on the "duplicate values" of a column.